# What is the syntax to create collection and to drop a collection in MongoDB?

Tags: python, r, mongodb

What is the syntax (we write in command line after we initialize mongo.exe) to create a collection and to drop a collection in MongoDB?

Create collection using the syntax:
`db.CreateCollection(name, options)`

Drop a collection syntax:
`Db.collectiom.drop()`

Answer (score 0):

In R with `mogolite` library you can do as follows:

```
library(mongolite)
library(ggplot2)

# Create collection
m <- mongo(collection = "mtcars")
m$insert(mtcars)

# Drop
m$drop()
```